# MapInfo/Mapbasic - test if a mapper is open

Tags: mapbasic

I have a custom menu that I created which opens a mappable table and I'm trying to work out how I open it when

1. there is no other .tab files or mapper windows open
2. there are other .tab files open which are in a mapper.

My question relates to the syntax of how I test if there is a mapper open. I then need to use the results of the test to work out whether I use 'map from' or 'add map'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to write a function that tests all open windows and checks if they are a mapper or not. If it finds a mapper it returns the window ID otherwise it returns 0. I haven't tested this but this should do it:

```
Include "MapBasic.def"

Declare Sub Main
Declare Function IsMapperOpen() as Integer

Sub Main()

Dim nWinID as Integer

    nWinID = IsMapperOpen()

    If nWinID > 0 then
        Note "A map window with ID " & nWinID & " is open"
    Else
        Note "No map window open"
    End if

End Sub


Function IsMapperOpen() as Integer

Dim numWins, i as Integer

    numWins = NumWindows()
    i = 0
    Do While(i < numWins)
        i = i + 1
        If WindowInfo(i, WIN_INFO_TYPE) = WIN_MAPPER then
            IsMapperOpen = WindowInfo(i, WIN_INFO_WINDOWID)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop

    IsMapperOpen = 0

End Function
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!